# ngRepeat and complex list

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this JSON-model from server:

```
[
{
  id:"open",
  title: "Opened",
  items: [
    { id:"id-1", img: "img/c/1.jpg", title: "Title 1" },
    { id:"id-2", img: "img/c/2.jpg", title: "Title 2" }
  ]
},
{
  id:"closed",
  title: "Closed",
  items: [
    { id:"id-5", img: "img/c/5.jpg", title: "Title 5" },
    { id:"id-6", img: "img/c/6.jpg", title: "Title 6" }
  ]
},
{
  id:"other",
  title: "Other",
  items: [] //empty
}
]
```

How I can get this view with AngularJS?

```
<section>
  <div class="group">
    Opened
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="img" style="background-image: url(img/c/1.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="store-item-info">Title 1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="img" style="background-image: url(img/c/2.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="store-item-info">Title 2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="group">
    Closed
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="img" style="background-image: url(img/c/5.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="store-item-info">Title 5</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="img" style="background-image: url(img/c/6.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="store-item-info">Title 6</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

ngRepeat or something else?
With plain array I haven't problem, but this is complex model (array with child items) and I want show it as plain list without nesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest `ngRepeat` directives! I don't think you can come up with *exactly* the markup you provided, but this should come close:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="group in groups">
    <div class="group">
        {{ group.title }}
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-ng-repeat="item in group.items">
        ... {{ item.title }} and so on.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. We'll have to change the layout